# Getting Instance of Same Class Two Times in Another Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have component A and I want to use component A in another component. IS that possible I can get the instance of A two times in Class B?

```
@Component
class A {
  public boolean isDoSomething();
}

@Component
class B {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("classA")
    private A classA;

    @Resource(name="classAExample")
    private A classExample;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to have the A injected twice inside B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get multiple instance, you need to define scope **prototype**.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class A {
  public boolean isDoSomething();
}
```

Look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) to get details.